# How do I find the NetBSD release for CentOS 6.5?

Tags: centos, compiling, package-management

I want to find the NetBSD rump package used for CentOS 6.5.  The list is present [here](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/).

I want to get the rump package for CentOS and after searching, I found [this version](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23729051/dir/centos_6/com/netbsd-rump-20130704-2.1.x86_64.rpm.html) of `netbsd-rump` used in CentOS 6:

This does not indicate the NetBSD package. How do I find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you can download the source RPM (SRPM) I'd download that and use `rpmbuild` to rebuild it myself.

#### Step #1 - install any dependencies

This will interrogate the downloaded SRPM and install anything that maybe missing.

```
$ sudo yum-builddep --nogpgcheck netbsd-rump-20130704-2.1.src.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * updates: mirrors.gigenet.com
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Getting requirements for netbsd-rump-20130704-2.1.src
No uninstalled build requires
```

#### Step #2 - setup rpmbuild

Install the RPM developer tools.

```
$ sudo yum install rpmdevtools
```

Setup your rpmbuild area.

```
$ rpmdev-setuptree
```

#### Step #3 - install developer tools

Install the developer tools (gcc, etc.).

```
$ sudo yum install gcc
```

You can also install a developers group, for example, "C Development Tools and Libraries".

```
$ yum groups list | grep Dev
   Development and Creative Workstation
   C Development Tools and Libraries
   Development Tools
   RPM Development Tools

$ yum groups install "C Development Tools and Libraries"
```

#### Step #4 - rebuild netbsd-rump

Now we rebuild rump.

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild netbsd-rump-20130704-2.1.src.rpm
```

#### Step #5 - install the resulting RPM.

```
$ sudo  yum localinstall \
    $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/netbsd-rump-20130704-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

#### References

- [CentOS RPM Tutorial Part 1 - Building your own RPMs](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/164/centos-rpm-tutorial-1/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I was able to build the rpm but I am still not able to find the netbsd package where the centos netbsd-rump was taken from.

Comment: For example, was it from netbsd-5.1, netbsd-6.0..etc

Comment: @Nikhil - I'm assuming that the version they used in the RPM is from the CVS source code repository directly. You could correlate the versions included with those versions of netbsd and the code repo.